# ListView and Activity share data

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

The sceen is I have a ListView displaying a list of restaurants and their address.

And I have a Activity which display the distance between two geopoints *(the user and the restaurant)* and also lots of information about the restaurant and a button which when clicked show the route from the users location to the restaurant on the map.

Problem: When the user click a ListView item i want to start an Activity which will show the correspondes resturants info.

For more clarification when user click ID- 0 *(first item in ListView)* then it should display result for that particular item.

How to do this?

Comment: What is the result which will be displayed when user click ID-0 (first item in ListView).Is it the the distance between two geopoints (the user and the restaurant)?

Comment: You probably looking for this [setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

Comment: ID-0 is the index value of the listview

Comment: Depends how you populate the ListView and where you store the data. For example, if you keep it in your Application class, you can pass the index to the next activity using Yashwanth's answer. If the ListView's adapter owns the data, you can put all of it into the extras (may be slow if its lots of data), if you use a content provider, you can pass the id for the new activity to query.

Comment: I m not storing data anywhere what i want is when user clicked on first listview item i.e ID-0 this 0 index will passed to the OtherActivty now as soon as this acivity start the array in this acivity store the array of distances(caluclated in another class). Now 0 is passed from listview and corresponds distance for that item is stored in array[0]. Now this a[0] should get displayed. can you tell me how to pass this index(ID) from list view and get this index or ID in another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the user clicks on the listView item.. you need to pass the information of the clicked restaurant to the new activity.. you do that by `putExtra` for `Intent` . you will have to do this in onItemClick for the listView. onItemClick returns the position of the click, may be that is what you need to pass as extra..

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Myactivity.this, NewActivityClass.class);
newIntent.putExtra("clickedId", position);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Comment: @ Yashwanth Kumar thanks for answer. how can i receive the position in another activity pls tell.??

Comment: use int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("clickedId", -1); , -1 is default when there is no clikedId.